# jp@gc-ResponsetimesOverTime label names

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Can some one please clarify me from the below screenshot what does  X10 ,X100,X1 000 refers next to the label name.

[image]

Thanks,
Rajani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are Logarithmic Scale of Base 10, 100, 1000 etc. Please check [this link](http://www.wikihow.com/Read-a-Logarithmic-Scale) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Naveen for your help!